# Left Join multiple tables on a parent table and subtract one column from the parent table

Tags: sql-server, join, subtraction

I have 3 tables (`donor_detail`, `items` & `store`) that I left joined on 1 parent table (`donated_items`), now there is a column `quantity` in the parent table which I wish to subtract from another table's column which is `issued_donation.issued_quantity`
here is my SQL which left joins but I am not understanding how should I subtract that column. i.e. `donated_items.quantity` -  `issued_donation.issued_quantity`

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.donor_name,t2.ID, t3.ID,t3.item_name, t4.store_name, t4.ID
FROM donated_items as t1
LEFT JOIN donor_detail  as t2 ON t1.donor_id = t2.ID
LEFT JOIN items  as t3 ON t1.item_id = t3.ID
LEFT JOIN stores  as t4 ON t1.store_id = t4.ID
```

Comment: What do you mean by substract? Do you mean you want to perform math against the two columns or do you mean you want to exclude some rows from the results?

Comment: @GordonLinoff my bad, its SQL server

Comment: @SeanLange yes I mean math as in minus / subtract, I have updated my question as well

Comment: @Programer . . . Probably not totally your bad.  Stack Overflow has a tendency to recommend MySQL . . . almost as if Oracle had a say in the matter (which Oracle does *not* ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, but I suspect you're talking about subtracting values, not columns. If I'm right, you have to join the other table (`issued_donation`) and than you can add to the selected fields something like `t1.quantity - t5.issued_quantity AS remainingQuantity`.